# How can I manipulate contents of a text file into a new output file

Tags: shell-script, awk, csv, text-formatting

I have an input text file that looks like this:

```
table columns are: 
number of vertices
total surface area (mm^2)
total gray matter volume (mm^3)
average cortical thickness +- standard deviation (mm)
integrated rectified mean curvature 
integrated rectified gaussian curvature
folding index
intrinsic curvature index
structure name

72 6.18 1307 87.23 987 0.566 2 3 1.8 SUBJECT_89765432/label/lh.APD57_20d.label

table columns are: 
....(repeat)
```

I want to create an output comma separated variable file that looks like this:

```
Id,surface area (mm^2),gray matter volume (mm^3),avg cortical thickness +- sd (mm),mean curvature,gaussian curvature,folding index,curvature index,hemi,ROI 
SUBJECT_89765432,72,6.18,1307,87.23,987,2,3,1.18, lh, 20d
SUBJECT_...(repeat)
```

how can I do this?
Thanks so much!

Comment: Could you please use some words to describe the transformation you're after? Just so we don't guess incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
sed '/SUBJECT_/!d;s/ /,/g;s/\(.*\),\(SUBJECT_[0-9]*\).*/\2,\1/'
```

- `/SUBJECT_/!d` removes all lines without the keyword (no need to build the header by script)
- `s/ /,/g` commas instead of spaces
- `s/\(.*\),\(SUBJECT_[0-9]*\).*/\2,\1/` to reordet

Answer (score 0):

The following script is a pretty hacky use of the perl `Text::CSV` module.  Normally, it is used to parse AND output correctly formatted CSV files but here I'm just using it for the `say()` method because I don't want to write my own code to properly quote fields where necessary (i.e. when they contain a space, line-feed, double-quote or a comma).

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -an
use Text::CSV qw(csv);

BEGIN {
  $csv=Text::CSV->new();
  # define our column headers in the right order.
  @columns = ("Id", "surface area (mm^2)", "gray matter volume (mm^3)",
    "avg cortical thickness +- sd (mm)", "mean curvature",
    "gaussian curvature", "folding index", "curvature index", "hemi", "ROI");
  # output them as a CSV field header.
  $csv->say(*STDOUT, \@columns );
};

# skip lines that don't begin with a digit
next unless /^\d/;

# Split the subject (field 10) into multiple sub-fields
# perl arrays start from 0, so the 10th field is $F[9].
# This will split it into an array like:
# SUBJECT 89765432 label lh APD57 20d label
#     0      1       2   3    4    5   6
my @subject=split(/[\/_.]/,$F[9]);

# Insert the first two of those sub-fields at the beginning of the input array
# as one new field joined by an underscore.
unshift @F, $subject[0] . "_" . $subject[1];

# Inserting that field means that field 10 is now field 11 - i.e. $F[9] is now $F[10].
# Replace it with the hemi value, and add a new ROI field at the end.
$F[10]=$subject[3];
push @F, $subject[5];

# print it as properly-formatted CSV.
$csv->say(*STDOUT, \@F);
```

Output:

```
Id,"surface area (mm^2)","gray matter volume (mm^3)","avg cortical thickness +- sd (mm)","mean curvature","gaussian curvature","folding index","curvature index",hemi,ROI
SUBJECT_89765432,72,6.18,1307,87.23,987,0.566,2,3,1.8,lh,20d
```